# How to setup Email subscription in SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Just wondering how to set up a SQL Server Reporting Services subscription to email the report as an attachment.

When setting up a usual subscription for a report, it seems to only provide a Windows File Share option.

Is there any clean instructions on how to set up email distributions of a report (to a list of email addresses) with the generated report sent as an attachment?

Kind regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I had to setup SMTP server and update the Email Settings in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx#bkmk_configure_for_local_or_remote_SMTP

Only after configuring this, does the Email option became available when setting up the subscription.